# Is it possible to close a SQLite DB connection from another method?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Can a SQLite DB connection hat is opened in one method and not closed, be closed in a later method?I have a need to do this programmatically.

```
private void SetConnection()

    {
        SQLiteConnection con;
        SQLiteDataAdapter da;
        SQLiteCommand cmd;
        DataSet ds;

        if (!File.Exists("data.db"))
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("data.db");

            string sql = @"CREATE TABLE Sites(
                           ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
                           SiteName            TEXT      NOT NULL,
                           IpAddress           TEXT       NOT NULL,
                           PortNo              TEXT       NOT NULL,
                           AuthType            TEXT       NOT NULL
                        );";
            con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=data.db;Version=3;");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//I want to leave this out  -- con.close();
// and close it later on in a different method
```

Is this even possible? Are there dangers to doing so?

Comment: That won't work as-is. You don't explicitly close the connection, but the object will be disposed sooner or later since its scope is that of the method. You will need to pass those variables to class fields if you want to reuse them

Comment: The other function would of course have to see the connection object in order to close it, but yes. That's the usual way. You shouldn't be opening and closing a connection every time you run a query; open the database once at startup, use that connection throughout the life of your program, and close it at shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the connection is part of the disposal method native to the class, however, its not a particularly clean method, and its fairly similar from the perspective other endpoint as a nonresponsive client.

You can properly dispose of a DB context from anywhere, so long as you possess a reference to the object needed to perform the disposal. There several ways to accomplish this.

First of all, is to just assign the reference to whichever object you expect to be performing the close operation. You would need to create a circumstance where both the DB context, and the object you expect to be performing the close exist in scope together, but thats something you an handle in initialization somewhere.

Hint hint, this is exactly the type of thing you might want to create a constructor for on whatever type is going to be managing your context.

For a more complicated scenario, such as if you're not certain from where the DB context will be handled, and if you want to make it far more flexible and generic, there is some delegate magic to be done, which in all will be similar to Functional Programming.

You would need to create a series of delegates to handle a few jobs, the number of which will vary depending on just how robust your parameters for working are.

First, you'll need to have a method on your DB context that actaully handles disposal, which you can then hand out to other objects as a Handler, which can be invoked out of scope to actually close down the connection.

Depending on the circumstances under which you expect to be closing down the connection from arbitrary scopes, you may also want a second method, who is called whenever you assign a delegate that closes out the connection. This would store the delegates which are able to close the connection, and whenever the connection attempts to close, first all the delegates are removed from their respective invocation lists, assuring that in later instances no Handlers try to point to objects which have been disposed.

At this point though, you're starting to delve into the territory of Threading, and unless the ability to drop and resume entire database contexts is important, you can likely scrape by with a reference in the expected type, or a Handler is the expected type is arbitrary until runtime.